# Custom JSON callback using Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm just trying to write a mobile app using https://jasonette.com/, but it wants backend specific JSON format for an each response, something like below:

```
{
  "$jason": {
    "head": {
      "title": "{ ˃̵̑ᴥ˂̵̑}",
      "actions": {
        "$foreground": {
          "type": "$reload"
        },
        "$pull": {
          "type": "$reload"
        }
      }
    },
    "body": {
      "header": {
        "style": {
          "background": "#ffffff"
        }
```

For test purposes I serialised regular django_user model:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

And it returns a JSON-object with a user list. But how I can customize this JSON with additional values and format it as a Jasonette wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change serialization behavior by overriding [`.to_representation()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) method in your serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

    def to_representation(self, user):
        data = super().to_representation(user)  # the original data

        return {
            '$jason': {
                'head': {
                    # ...
                },
                'body': data,
                # ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This is an amazing solution in my case, but it can return only one item not a list of entities )) For example, my function     def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data) , without ".to_representation()" return list of objects, wit the function only one item ))

Answer (score 3):

The serializer will handle conversion of the object instance to a dictionary of primitive datatypes and vice-versa (just like a django `Form`). If you want to augment the JSON response, override the corresponding view method. As an example, you can do something like the following in your view:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        data = serializer.data
        data.update({"foo": "bar"})
        return Response(data)
```